# Can I defined variable from function to outside scope?

Tags: php

In PHP, I always see example to get data from function like this :

```
function getSomeData(){
   //this function will return a array of data
   $data_A = 'foo';
   $data_B = 'bar';
   $data_C = 42;     
   return array('data_A'=>$data_A, 'data_B'=>$data_B, 'data_C'=>$data_C, )
}

//1. we call the function
$models = getSomeData(); 

//2. Now we need to define the variable by the return value.
$data_A = $models['data_A'];
$data_B = $models['data_B'];
$data_C = $models['data_C'];

//3. Then we can do whatever with those defined variable
doSomething($data_A);
doSomethingElse($data_B);
```

That looks usual. Now, How about this :

```
function getSomeData(){

   $data_A = 'foo';
   $data_B = 'bar';
   $data_C = 42;

   someMagicFunction($data_A); //this function will set variable at the upper level scope
   someMagicFunction($data_B);
   someMagicFunction($data_C);

   return true;
}

//1. we call the function
getSomeData(); 

//2. Then we use it right here
doSomething($data_A);
doSomethingElse($data_B);
```

What I  want is try to skip step 2, I will need a function that can "set variable at the upper level scope". 
Sometimes I think step 2 is somehow 'unnecessary' -- I think without those the code can be much simply and clean.

Suppose the code is inside a class or anonymous function, not in root level, Would it be possible ? If not, why PHP don't allow me to doing this ? Is there any alternative way to do the task ? (reduce duplicate define in function and define outside again)

Comment: It's a bad idea to do this, since scoping is mechanism to safeguard your variables. However, you can use globals to do this; http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.globals.php

Comment: "Suppose the code is inside a class or anonymous function, not in root level"

Comment: Uhm... using class variables and `$this`? I am probably not understanding your question well enough... Please give an exact example of how you want things to work...

Answer (score 2):

If a function returns an array. It does so with reason. A function should only use that what is given to it, and if needed return a result. It should NEVER set any global variables (unless the function is called setGlobalVariable, then it has a reason ).

If you want to map a returned array to variables. use [list](http://php.net/manual/en/function.list.php)

```
list($a,$b,$c) = getSomeData();
```

Comment: It is a good idea, although the "Syntax" looks strange to me. It should be better like `list(getSomeData(), array('a','b','c'))` then makes more sense.

Comment: It looks like this : only a upper level scope "should" able to control/make changes to lower level scope(by using parameter when calling, or call some defined function inside lower level scope), but a lower level scope "should never" do effect to a upper level one. But is there any further explanation about why is it ?

Comment: imo you syntax looks more strange. There the list function would create variables in an 'upper level'. This is bad. Why you ask? Common sense. It keeps code clean. Less bugs, ... These are rules made by programmers who are sick of having to debug stupid global $varA; code

Comment: In my example there's not going to make some bug. I'd like say it would be bad, just like "global" function -- it can be bad depends how the user use it, but sometime we might need it. However I don't think "it possibility make bad code" == it should not exits.

Comment: I have told a reason "why i ask" in my question --- "reduce duplicate define in function and define outside again". In this moment, yet nobody explain the main reason why that's bad, what will happen if we do this...so far. Still even it does have lots of disadvantage, I'd like to using this function to make the coding faster for making "quick and dirty (but working) prototype". and  making the code clean later, we all know we can't makes perfect code in one time, perfection is a process.

Answer (score -1):

Try This...

```
$data_A = '';
$data_B = '';
$data_C = '';

function getSomeData(){
 //this function will set variable at the upper level scope
 global $data_A, $data_B, $data_C; //Using global

 $data_A = 'foo';
 $data_B = 'bar';
 $data_C = 42;

 return true;
}

//1. we call the function
getSomeData(); 

//2. Then we use it right here
doSomething($data_A);
doSomethingElse($data_B);
```

Comment: as RichardBernad said, this is a bad idea, its just the way that you can achieve your output...

Comment: Why `someMagicFunction` still exists in your example ?

Comment: Using global will change at the root level, but I am asking "the upper level".

Comment: In My point of view, there is a "missing link" when A calling B, B can't accesses to A, or even don't know there was a A.